# Alerting/Azure Monitor: “tsdb.HandleRequest() response error &{Request failed status: 400 Bad Request A 0xc001403600 [] [] []}”

Tags: grafana, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, grafana-alerts

I am using a grafana dashboard for Azure Monitor for containers- Metrics but while creating the alarm for CPU utilization in the Kubernetes cluster, I get the error mentioned above.

Here is the graph for the CPU utilization :

[image: img1]

And also I am attaching the condition I am using to create alert:

[image: img2]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Please advice!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Graph of CPU utilization and configuration to create alert looks correct. As per the error message (request failed status: 400 Bad Request), this looks like the alert notification settings might have some issue (most likely the server is expecting different format of data and throwing 400 to the request).

Grafana documentation for alerts - [link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/notifications/#list-of-supported-notifiers)

What is the mode of notification you are using? Predefined one or custom webhook based notification?